# How to rewrite URLs for all views in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp-1.3

I am new to CakePHP.

I want to rewrite all the view files with the `.HTML` extension to URLs.

Users should not be able to see the original URLs.

**Example**:

If I have 
`/controller/view/2` then it should be displayed in URL as
`/controller/view.HTML` only.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to put in some rewrite rules on the web server. You can pass the parameters using POST variables (thereby eliminating the '2' in your example, as in `/controller/views/`) and then using `mod_rewrite` access the URL from `view.html`.